# How can Solr fieldTypes be shared between multiple cores?

Tags: solr

Is it possible to share Solr `fieldType`s defined in `schema.xml` between multiple cores?

I have a number of cores in Solr and find myself re-defining `fieldType`s which are based only on built-in filters and tokenizers. e.g.

```
<fieldType name="exact" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

I know i can write my own `Field` class and share this between the cores, but it seems silly to create a dependency on custom code when the custom code would only be configuring standard filters. Is there a better way?

Note that the above example is simple in comparison to some others (which configure stop words and character conversions, etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of a way to share fieldTypes between cores. However, if your cores all have the same schema (e.g. same fields and fieldTypes), you can share that between multiple cores and only need to update the schema in one place. Please see this Solr User Mailing list post: [Sharing Schema with multiple cores](http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/Sharing-a-schema-with-multiple-cores-td2466048.html) for setup details.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately they do not share the same fields.

Comment: See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3087?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:all-tabpanel  If it's fixed it'll be possible to do it. So maybe eventually ;)

Answer (score 2):

Sharing a fieldType like "common" definitions in the schema.xml, solrconfig.xml across multiple cores is possible using [XInclude](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrConfigXml#XInclude).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- common-types.xml -->
<types>
<fieldType name="exact" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
</types>
```

And use it in your schema.xml like below:

```
<schema version="1.1">
  <types>
   <!-- Other types  here -->
  </types>
  <xi:include href="file:/path/to/common-types.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"></xi:include>
</schema>
```

Notice: Included XML file must be a single root node.